# UITableView Index without magnifying glass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create an Indexed UITableView with out the magnifying glass icon.
I realize the UITableViewIndexSearch is creating the icon in the index but I do not know what to replace it with. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

return index;}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the array of section index titles
NSArray *searchArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];
return [searchArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:self.fetchedResultsController.sectionIndexTitles];}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add `UITableViewIndexSearch` in `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`. Simply return the array from your fetchedResultsController.

Comment: - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {  
 NSArray *fetchedObjects = [fetchedResultsController_ sectionIndexTitles];

 return fetchedObjects;
}

Answer (score 4):

Simply replace it with nothing. Just leave the `UITableViewIndexSearch` constant out of your array.